# Concurrency / UI update problem when starting an activity

Tags: android, user-interface, concurrency

I have an activity, which when starting (onCreate or onStart) needs to manipulate some views, and then *maybe* immediately starts another activity (a interstitial ad in its own activity).

There seems to be a problem with the order/concurrency: The ad activity is opened, and then the manipulated view R.id.productlist_filterbar from the previous activity is drawn on top of the interstitial ad activity.

(Simplified) code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.productlist);

    // Do some init stuff ..

    // Manipulate the GUI
    findViewById(R.id.productlist_filterbar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // If executed, then a new intent is fired in here to open the interstitial ad
    if (..we have an ad..) {            
        Intent i  = new Intent(this, AdViewActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(i);               
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, 0);            
    }

}
```

What happens when I call startActivity() while there are still pending GUI modifications?

And, what would be the best solution for this case?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a flag set in `onAttachedToWindow()` callback and then check for this flag in `onWindowFocusChanged()` if set then start the ad activity and reset the flag.

```
void onAttachedToWindow() {
    mFlag = true;
}

void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
     if (hasFocus && mFlag) {
        // start ad activity.

        mFlag = false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks - wasn't aware of onAttachedToWindow(), this can solve my issue.